# Reading a comma-separated string (not text file) in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, parsing, numbers

I want to read a string in Matlab (**not an external text file**) which has numerical values separated by commas, such as

```
a = {'1,2,3'}
```

and I'd like to store it in a vector **as numbers**. Is there any function which does that? I only find processes and functions used to do that with text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the eval function to "evaluate" the vector. If that is the structure, I will also use the cell2mat to get the '1,2,3' text (this can be approached by other methods too.

```
% Generate the variable "a" that contains the "vector"
a = {'1,2,3'};
% Generate the vector using the eval function 
myVector = eval(['[' cell2mat(a) ']']);
```

Let me know if this solution works for you

Comment: @Pablo glad to hear that worked, but be aware that [using `eval` like this is discouraged](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html). For a one-off data import it's OK, but I wouldn't use it in code that other people will use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for **[sscanf](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html?s_tid=srchtitle_sscanf_1)**

> `A = sscanf(str,formatSpec)` reads data from `str`, converts it according
> to the format specified by `formatSpec`, and returns the results in an
> array. `str` is either a character array or a string scalar.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the **[str2num](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html)** function:

`vec = str2num('1,2,3')`

If you have to use the cell `a`, per your example, it would be: `vec=str2num(a{1})`

There are some security warnings in the documentation to consider so be cognizant of how your code is being employed.

Another, more flexible, option is **[textscan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)**.  It can handle strings as well as file handles.

Here's an example:

```
cellResult = textscan('1,2,3', '%f','delimiter',',');
vec = cellResult{1};
```